# how to put the text next to image?

Tags: html, css

My wish would be to move the text next to the image. I have put these two inside a div and floatet the image right, but now i cant move the text down with margin-op?why and what could i improve?

```css
.text{
width: 50px;
font-size: 27px;
float: left;
font-weight: bold;
}
.image{
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
clear: left;
float: right;

}
.parent{
background-color: pink;
height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="schrott.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
<p class="text">ihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnii</p>
<img src="Pictures\—Pngtree—triangle neon color glowing border_4072770.png" class="image">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to point you in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/h5o607e1/1/

The biggest thing for you to look at here is the position and display settings for both the text and image: `position: relative;` and `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

What about using a flexbox (`display: flex`):

```css
.text{
  width: 49%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  align-self: center; /*Vertically align text*/
}
.image{
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red; /*for illustration*/

}
.parent{
  background-color: pink;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="schrott.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
<p class="text">ihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnihnii</p>
<img src="Pictures\—Pngtree—triangle neon color glowing border_4072770.png" class="image">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is CSS, level *1* people: just use `float`. The value for `float` is `left`, `right` or `none` ([float on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)). The order of the elements should have an effect too.

```
<p>Placeholder...</p>
<img alt="Placeholder" src="4072770.png" style="float: left;" />

<p>Placeholder...</p>
<img alt="Placeholder" src="4072770.png" style="float: right;" />

<img alt="Placeholder" src="4072770.png" style="float: left;" />
<p>Placeholder...</p>

<img alt="Placeholder" src="4072770.png" style="float: right;" />
<p>Placeholder...</p>
```

Also don't put spaces or uppercase letters in URLs until you get more advanced or you'll create more headaches than it's worth.